# APEX 20.1 cannot set SWITCH component to READONLY dynamically

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, readonly

Is there any workaround that can set SWITCH component/item to read-only.

I can do it for TEXT FIELD but not for SWITCH.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little light on detail. You can set a Switch item to read only using the Read Only configuration section.

For example, Type = "Item = Value", Item = P1_SWITCH, Value = 'READ_ONLY'.

Note that this changes it from a little switch graphic to a text display that reads Off or On, which may not be clear to your users.